# WCF: issue with tcp binding in IISExpress

Tags: wcf, iis-express, nettcpbinding

I have a wcf project and I'm creating a client to test it. For some reasons, on my local machine I can run the service only within IIS Express from visual studio. After I start the project, I'm trying to connect to the service from a client, but I'm getting an error:

> You have tried to create a channel to a service that does not support
>   .Net Framing. It is possible that you are encountering an HTTP
>   endpoint.

I've read [this](https://randypaulo.wordpress.com/2011/11/14/iis-7-how-to-enable-net-tcp/) and [this](http://marc.bloggingabout.net/2007/10/23/wcf-hosting-non-http-protocols-in-iis-7-0/) but they're discussing about IIS and not IIS Express.

Here is my code from the client:

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:64255/MyService.svc");
ChannelFactory<IMyInterface> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMyInterface>(binding, address);

channelFactory.Open();
IMyInterface _clientProxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
((IClientChannel)_clientProxy).Open();
```

And when I'm calling the method `Open`, I'm getting the error above...

Please note that the service accepts only net.tcp protocol.

What do I need to change to call this service hosted in IIS Express from my client?

Edit: when I'm running the project from visual Studio, in the browser I'm seeing the url: http://localhost:64255/MyService.svc

Answer (score 2):

Long story short: IIS Express does not support non-HTTP protocols such as net.tcp.  IIS Express only supports HTTP and HTTPS as its protocol